# Rails - Simple_Form_For - Setting default value for time field that ignores database attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails, simple-form

I wish to create an edit form that ignores the current values, or even better performs a calculation on them before displaying them. In my case I wish to add an hour to every datetime displayed.

I've tried:

```
f.input "#{day}_open".to_sym,:as=>:time,:label=>false, :minute_step=>5, input_html: { value: f.object.mon_open + 1.hour }
```

And:

```
f.input "#{day}_open".to_sym,:as=>:time,:label=>false, :minute_step=>5, input_html: { id: "#{day}".to_s + '_open', value: f.object.mon_open + 1.hour }
```

And:

```
f.input "#{day}_open".to_sym,:as=>:time,:label=>false, :minute_step=>5, default: f.object.mon_open + 1.hour
```

With text fields the following works:

```
= f.input :meta_title, input_html: { value: 'bla' }
```

However not with time fields. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

In case anyone else is curious, you need to use selected rather than input_html:

```
f.input "#{day}_open".to_sym, as: :time, label: false, minute_step: 5, selected: Time.now
```